# How to remove unwanted jars included in the lib using maven

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I am using viewservlets.jar file in my application. I added the following dependency in my pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>viewservlets</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

After packaging I could see birt runtime jar also in my lib. Similarly many other jars. I am not sure how all these jars included in my folder.
I am using java 8. Still I can see some jars related to jdk14 (e.g *bcmail-jdk14-1.38.jar , bcprov-jdk14-1.38.jar* ) . That is also multiple times. The war files are getting big because of this.

**Update**

In the runtime package there are many other packages can be found. If i count it is more than 30 nos. In this i need only one jar file. So is there any way to include only one jar instead of using exclusion for the remaining 30+ entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven automatically resolves dependencies transitively, i.e. it adds the dependencies of your dependencies to the WAR as well.

This way Maven makes sure that you do not run into ClassNotFound exceptions because `viewservlets` is trying to call something that does not exist.

Of course, it may be the case that some of those dependencies are not really called at runtime. If you are sure that a given artifact is never called, you can exclude it with an `exclusion`. But it is generally hard to determine that and it is probably not worth the effort.

EDIT: an example

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
  <artifactId>viewservlets</artifactId>
  <version>4.4.1</version>
  <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
        <groupId>*</groupId>
        <artifactId>*</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.something</groupId>
  <artifactId>otherdependency</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am trying to mavenize the old project.in my application I only need viewservlets.jar file.

Comment: You can add `<exclusions><exclusion><groupId>*</groupId><artifactId>*</artifactId></exclusion></exclusions>` to the dependency, this will exclude all transitive dependencies.

Comment: I just checked the package org.birt.runtime. I only need one jar file remaining all are excluded. So any way to do it one short. Include viewservlet and exclude rest ?. If I use exclusion I have to mention each artifact that will make my pom.xml more lengthy and complicated.

Comment: Just exclude all and add the jar file as additional dependency.

Comment: How to do that ? can you please share an example ?